# C#: Storing a data path from an OpenFileDialog into a Variable?

Tags: c#, forms, variables

In the following c# class displaying a `Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` how could I store the data path into the variable called `m_settings`?

```
private SomeKindOfData m_settings;
public void ShowSettingsGui()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    ofd.Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] filePath = ofd.FileNames;
        string[] safeFilePath = ofd.SafeFileNames;
    }
        m_settings = //<-- ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
m_settings = ofd.FileName;
```

EDIT: Actually, now I'm not sure if you wanted the folder path. In that case:

```
m_settings = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);
```